# Find command shows the files are present but not found inside the directory

Tags: command-line, 18.04, scripts, find, zsh

I tried search a files using following find command

```
find . -type f -mtime +18 -name '*[-.]20[0-9][0-9\-]*' -exec basename {} \;
```

I can see the files output like .

```
handh2.access.20210429.bz2

handh2.access.20210428.bz2

handh2.access.20210502.bz2

handh2.access.20210430.bz2
```

But files are not in the directory

```
root@web38 135 0 # stat handh2.access.20210429.bz2

stat: cannot stat 'handh2.access.20210429.bz2': No such file or directory

root@web38 136 1 # ls | grep "handh2.access.20210429.bz2"

root@web38 137 1 #
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: `find` also searches subdirectories unless you use the option `-maxdepth 0`.

Comment: With `basename` you have stripped the directory path from the filenames. Try with `find . -type f -mtime +18 -name '[-.]20[0-9][0-9-]' -ls` and you will find the whole path (including directories).

Comment: instead of `basename` use `%` directives `-printf %f\\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As several people commented, your `find` command used the `basename` utility to explicitly strip off the directory components of the matching files. As a result, you don't know which (sub)directory those files actually reside in.

You can find the full path to the files by changing your `find` call so that it prints the full paths:

```
find . -type f -mtime +18 -name '*[-.]20[0-9][0-9\-]*' -ls
```

or you can find each one individually:

```
find . -type f -mtime +18 -name handh2.access.20210429.bz2
```